# Implicit Function Theorem (Three Equations in Three Unknowns)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Help me in proving the following theorem:

Implicit Function Theorem (Three Equations in Three Unknowns)

1. $F(u, v, w, x, y, z)$, $G(u, v, w, x, y, z)$, $H(u, v, w, x, y, z)$ $\in \;\; C^{1}$ in  $ N_{\delta}(u_{0},v_{0},w_{0},x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$.
2. $ F(u_{0},v_{0},w_{0},x_{0},y_{0},z_{0}) = G(u_{0},v_{0},w_{0},x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})=H(u_{0},v_{0},w_{0},x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})=0.$
3. $ \frac{\partial (F,G,H)}{\partial (u,v,w)} \ne 0$ at $ (u_{0},v_{0},w_{0},x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$.

$\Rightarrow$ There exist unique functions $f(x,y,z)$, $g(x,y,z)$ and $h(x,y,z)$ and a positive number $\eta$ such that

(A) $f(x,y,z)$, $g(x,y,z)$ and $h(x,y,z)$ $\in \;\; C^{1}$, $|x-x_{0}|<\eta$, $|y-y_{0}|<\eta$, $|z-z_{0}|<\eta$.

(B) $ f(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})=u_{0}$, $ g(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})=v_{0}$, $ h(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})=w_{0}$.

(C) $F(f,g,h,x,y,z)=G(f,g,h,x,y,z)=H(f,g,h,x,y,z)=0$, $|x-x_{0}|<\eta$, $|y-y_{0}|<\eta$, $|z-z_{0}|<\eta$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried following the procedure used for 2 equations with 2 variables given by Widder, Advanced Calculus. But I couldn't proceed.